# Regular expression to validate password needs mix digits and letters(python)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to meet the password criteria which should be 6-8 characters long. It consists of alphanumeric characters with a mixture of digits and letters.

```
import re
def validate(passwd): 
    reg = r"[a-z0-9]{6,8}"  # regular expression
    match = re.match(reg, passwd)
    if match:
        return "Valid password."
    else:
        return "Invalid password."
```

`reg = r"[a-z0-9]{6,8}"  # regular expression`

However, what I wrote here still matches all letters or all digits pattern.

OR

`reg = r"(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z]).{6,8}"`

This one looks closer but still unable to exclude the pattern which contains `_`

Would like to seek advice how to do it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,8}$
```

Add anchors to make it strict match.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Even adding ^ in the regex, this pattern "12340_ah" still matches.

Comment: it works! I also tried (?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,8}, this works too. Seems that it's ok to ignore the strict match ^. Thank you!